# How to allow user to input files in react native?

Tags: css, javascript, react-native

I am building a react native app and I need the user to be able to add a file from their phone (pdf, doc, etc). Is can't seem to find a native component for this use? Does anyone have any recommendations on how to go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this module. I hope it'll work for you.

`npm i react-native-document-picker`

Here is the npm package link: [Npm-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-document-picker)

Here is the one of example using this package: [example](https://www.itechinsiders.com/how-to-upload-single-or-multiple-documents-in-react-native/)